# android Check if user is already Logged in

Tags: android, authentication, sharedpreferences

I want to check if the user is already logged in the app so if the user is not logged he will be directed to `Login.class` and if the user is already logged he will be directed to his `Profile.class`.

I saw a tutorial about checking user logged in from the internet using `SplashActivity.class` but I tried it and didn't work for me, I don't know maybe I just don't get how it works since I'm new in **programming**

my Codes:

**Login class**

```
    public class DocLogin extends Fragment {

    ImageView ivIcon;
    TextView tvItemName, tvRegister;
    EditText user, pass;
    Button btnLogin;
    String username, password;
    SQLController dbcon;
    SharedPreferences sh_Pref;
    Editor editor;

    private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;


    public DocLogin() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.doc_log_in, container, false);

        dbcon = new SQLController(getActivity());
        dbcon.open();

        // Log in
        user = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etUser);
        pass = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        btnLogin = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

        // Sign up
        tvRegister = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvRegDoc);
        tvRegister.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        tvRegister.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new DocReg());
                ft.commit();
                return false;
            }
        });

        // btnLogin onClickListener
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                dbcon = new SQLController(getActivity());
                dbcon.open();

                username = user.getText().toString();
                password = pass.getText().toString();
                sharedPreferences();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Login Successful", 20).show();

                Log.v("LoginDetails", user.getText().toString() + "../.."
                        + pass.getText().toString());
                Cursor cur = dbcon.getuser_information(user.getText()
                        .toString(), pass.getText().toString());
                if (cur.getCount() != 0) {
                    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new DocProfile());
                    ft.commit();
                } else {
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            getActivity()).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Login Error");
                    alertDialog
                            .setMessage("Doctor Code and Password does not match");
                    alertDialog.setButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    // dismiss dialog
                                }
                            });
                    alertDialog.show();
                }

            }
        });

        return view;
    }


    public void sharedPreferences() {

        sh_Pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Login Credentials", PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = sh_Pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);
        editor.putString("Username", username);
        editor.putString("Password", password);
        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

Please guide me the correct way to achieve my objective.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add alreadylogin field in logintable in database.if user first time login,set alreadylogin field as true else by default false.Each time you  must check alreadylogin field.if the field is true,you must redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows that your preferences are set. So put the following where you wanna check whether you are logged in or not.

```
SharedPreferences sh_Pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Login Credentials", PRIVATE_MODE);
boolean check = sh_Pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
if(check){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Profile.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

If user has already logged in then user will be directed to `Profile.class`

Comment: can I use this in SplashActivity ?

Comment: You can use this snippet anywhere in your app where you want to check login.